# Shlomo Yosef Zevin a Rav at 9 years old

Tags: rabbis, semicha

Rabbi Shlomo Yosef Zevin, according to [here](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=12691&st=&pgnum=27) was given smicha by the Aruch HaShulchan.  Assuming that the Aruch HaShulchan ordained Rabbi Zevin at the very end of his life, Rabbi Zevin would have been no more than 9 years old. Was this indeed the case, and is it indeed possible for someone under the age of Bar Mitzvah to become ordained as a Rabbi?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Aruch Hashulchan died in 1908 ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yechiel_Michel_Epstein), see footnote 9), and according to the article you brought, Rav Zevin was born somewhere between 1886-1888 (in fact, it was 1888). Therefore, he could have received Semicha from the Aruch Hashulchan when he was in his late teens or early 20s.

Comment: yup.  for some reason i was thinking 1908 -1888 was 10.